# Render Environment removal

Tags: rendering

How do I  render a scene with environmental reflections but without environment(HDR in this case) rendering itself ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6UWG.jpg  ( I want part in red not to render which is an hdr)  .  This is my scene https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Xzo.jpg.